# Hide header on some pages in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

Is there a way I can hide my page header for only some routes in React Router? My issue now is that my `App` component renders my `Main` component, which contains my `BrowserRouter`, and my `Header` is rendered in my `App` component, so I have no way of rendering the header based on the route path.

Here's some code:

**`App.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './Main';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';

const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header/>
        <Main/>
        <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

**`Main.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

const Main = () => (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
        </Switch>
    </main>
);

export default Main;
```

In this application, I would like to hide the header and footer on the login page.

Comment: You can either use Context/Provider/Consumer to do this, or you change your logic and have header and footer as a child of your home page and not your login page. You could also do this with a store specifically for UI with mobx.

Comment: @kemicofa if I have the header and footer be children of the home page and not login page, won't they be re-rendered upon navigation to another page that also has a header and footer?

Comment: Yes you're right (but not performant heavy and easiest solution). However, if you wish to keep your current setup have a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html (recommended) or https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react. They can both solve this problem. You could eventually work with refs but that's antipattern and best to stay away from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Redux. This was the best option because I have over twenty pages (only 3 shown in code below) on all of which the visibility of the header/footer vary. I created one reducer for the header and one for the footer. Here was my solution:

```
import ...

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                {this.props.header ? <Header/> : ''}
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
                </Switch>
                {this.props.footer ? <Footer/> : ''}
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state;
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use withRouter Higher-Order component to access props.location object in your App component and check if a user is on login or signup page using `props.location.pathname`

```
import {BrowserRouter, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => (
   <BrowserRouter>

     {
      props.location.pathname!=='/login' ? <Header/>:null
     }
        <Main/>
        <Footer/>

   </BrowserRouter>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 2):

in react-router-dom v6 there is a hook useLocation that gets the url as it changes
using it is 100% helpful and solves this issue.

```
function App () {
let location = useLocation();
      return (
           <BrowserRouter>
                {location.pathname === '/login' && location.pathname==='/signup' && <Header/>}
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
                </Switch>
                {location.pathname === '/login' && location.pathname==='/signup' && <Footer/>}
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

props kept coming back undefined in my class component

```
{window.location.pathname !== "/app" ? (
          <NavBar />
) : null}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
<Switch>
          {authRoutes.map(({ path, component: C }) => (
            <Route
              key={`${C}-route`}
              path={path}
              render={(props) => (
                <div className="app__activePage">
                  <C {...props} />
                </div>
              )}
            ></Route>
          ))}

          {routes.map(({ path, component: C }) => (
            <Route
              key={`${C}-route`}
              path={path}
              render={(props) => (
                <div className="app__activePage">
                  <Header />
                  <C {...props} />
                </div>
              )}
            ></Route>
          ))}
</Switch>
```

I usually define all of my routes in another file and export them by group. This allows me to:

1. Define all of the routing in one place
2. Handle different routing groups more cleanly

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use useEffect to monitor the pathname, but nothing an rerender the page, so it didn't work out. However,
I was able to not showing the footer in home Page but others by create another components inside the App.tsx.

```
import {Footer} from "./components/Footer";

export const ShowFooter = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  if (location.pathname !== "/") return <Footer />;
  else return <></>;
};
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        </Routes>
        <ShowFooter />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).