# How can I make conditional Header with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to making conditional `Header` page by page, which means that I don't  want to show `Header` at `Home` page and I want to show `Header` at the other pages like posts page, projects page, etc..

I've tried to think how can I solved this problem, but there was no special way to working with `react-router-dom`. Of course, it may be only hard for me.

Whatever, I can't solve above problem is same.

So, this is current code:

```
<div className="ui container">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Route exact path="/">
    <Route exact path="/posts">
    <Route exact path="/project">
    <Route exact path="/profile">
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

and I want fix it like this:

```
<div className="ui container">
  <BrowserRouter>
    {() => { 
      if(path !=="/") 
        return <Header />;
      } else {
        return ;
    }}
    <Route exact path="/">
    <Route exact path="/posts">
    <Route exact path="/project">
    <Route exact path="/profile">
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a `Switch`:

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={null} />
      <Route component={Header} />
<Switch>

...
```

doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 4):

without Switch , you can do this :

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    {window.location.pathname !== "/" ? <Header /> : null}
    <Route exact path="/">
    <Route exact path="/posts">
    <Route exact path="/project">
    <Route exact path="/profile">
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is It! thanks! for answer. It worked with your code!

Comment: humm.... I think this code makes another problem. Header doesn't render although link was changed. It shows Header within "/(something)", if I access with "/' then it doesn't render header. here is deme link http://acd2ef3d.ngrok.io/

Answer (score 1):

There are ways you can do it.

- You can use withRouter(), an Higher Order Component to wrap your component. So, with that that component will have access to the BrowserRouter props.
- You can use Redux, We the posts page/component is mounted you set a isheader state to false. then you can use this state to condition the Header component.

A reference link:- [Hide header on some pages in react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971917/hide-header-on-some-pages-in-react-router-dom)

Another method is to wrap those route that will have the header with a parent component example:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => (
            <div>
              <Header />
                {children}
            </div>
          )
        const App = ()=> (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Layout>
                      <Route exact path="/posts" component={..}>
                      <Route exact path="/project" component={..}>
                      <Route exact path="/profile" component={..}>
                    </Layout>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

Comment: Thank for kind anwser!